# getting warning not secured when using certificate for my site in linux

Tags: java, security, networking, middleware

I am getting a warning :

> not secured for Chrome but in IE it is working fine
>   site url :-https://10.71.8.165:8443/NextGene/

Detailed warning:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 10.71.8.165 (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
>   NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Help improve *Safe Browsing* by sending some system information and page content to Google. Privacy policy

This server could not prove that it is `10.71.8.165`; its security certificate does not specify *Subject Alternative Names*. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Proceed to 10.71.8.165 (unsafe)

I have tried to give SAN same as of ip `10.71.8.165`, but still facing same issue.

please, suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address has a DNS entry that matches the certificate's subject and, more importantly, is in the certificate's list of Subject Alternative Names (SANs), use that.  If your organization does not have a DNS entry for the IP address, add a DNS entry that maps to that IP address and is contained in the certificate's list of SANs.

Comment: this is my prod URL :https://iims.jci.com:8443/NextGene/                                                                                 and iims.jci.com maps to the ip :-10.71.8.165                                                                                               in this case what will be DNS. SAN can not accept full url because of :                                                    like in google,amazon dns name is google.com, amazon.com like that                                                   here in my case what will the value of DNS

Answer (score 0):

Thank you
Yes it is working for chrome browser but still my site is not working for mozilla.

mozilla version is :70.0
error:-Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

Someone could be trying to impersonate the site and you should not continue.

Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust iims.jci.com:8443 because its certificate issuer is unknown, the certificate is self-signed, or the server is not sending the correct intermediate certificates.

Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER